# NoSQL DB (directed graphs) for Java/GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, nosql, neo4j, spring-data-graph

I'm looking for no-sql directed graphs DB engine for GWT application. Requirements are:

1. SQLite-like simplicity.
2. Has a tool to explore/modify its structure.
3. Doesn't require being installed (or very easy to install without fixing configuration files and other stuff).
4. No special requirements for performance.

What should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) looks suitable. It is simple to use, has an eclipse-based tool for exploring the structure visually (although it is not perfect), and can be run embedded (no installation).

Comment: There's a web-based admin tool with visualization as well: [webadmin](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/webadmin-data.html). You can use it with embedded mode as well, see [using the server with an embedded database](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html).